# $in returning nothing when array is empty

Tags: mongodb

This is my backend code for filters :

```
 db.collection("users")
      .find({
        $or: [
          { job: { $in: myFilters.jobs } },
          { role: myFilters.role }
        ]
      })
```

it works really well, when

```
myFilters.jobs = ["manager","user"]
```

The problem is when myFilters.jobs is an empty array [""], it should return all documents.

Currently, this is returning nothing, while I need it to return all docs :

```
myFilters.jobs = [""]
```

How could I do that, please ?

I've tried out this with no luck :

```
db.collection("users")
      .find({
            $or: [
                $cond: {
                   if: { $ne: [myFilters.jobs, ""] },
                     then:  { job: myFilters.jobs },
                    else: { job: { $in: myFilters.jobs } }
                   },
                { role: myFilters.role }
            ]

      })
```

Comment: You should probably simply remove the condition entirely if `jobs` is empty.

Comment: How to do that without using Javascript code ? Is there any way to do it with find() , because I will soon have 60 differents filters ... Am I forced to use a if /else or a switch  js code to manipulate my filters ?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your condition according to the values you get like this:

Using [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html):

```
db.collection("users")
      .find({ $where: function() {
        return myFilters.jobs.includes(this.job) || this.role === myFilters.role
      }})
```

JS only:

```
const cond = {};

if(myFilters.jobs.length === 0) {
  cond.role = myFilters.role;
} else {
  cond.$or = [
          { job: { $in: myFilters.jobs } },
          { role: myFilters.role }
  ];
}

db.collection("users")
      .find(cond)
```

**Update** according to the OP's answer:

```
db.collection("users")
      .find({ $where: function() {
        let filter = true;
        if(myFilters.jobs && myFilters.jobs.length) filter = myFilters.jobs.includes(this.members);
        if(myFilters.role) filter = filter && this.name === myFilters.role;
        return filter;
      }})
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i've ended up with a similar system but I wonder if I could avoid the JS code ? Because, I will soon have way much more filters, like 20  or 50 !

Comment: Ive tried with your solution $where but it doesnt seem to filter

Comment: Maybe $filter would be better ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm trying to explain the solution I've found :

**1st .** In a node ws, I'm receiving filters, and cleaning them with this function :
This function removes emptys objects or arrays(It is when a user doesn't pick any filter inside of the app).

This is the JSON filters I'm receiving , please notice that, for example, role is empty, because the user has not chosen any role filter.

```
{"filters":{"role":"","jobs":["database"]}}
```

It goes through this function, so role gets deleted :

```
clean(myFilters);
function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (
      obj[propName] === null ||
      obj[propName] === undefined ||
      obj[propName] === "" ||
      !obj[propName].length
    ) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
}
```

`2nd` , 
Then, I'm pushing the filters dynamically like this :

```
var find = {};

  find.$and = [];

  if (myFilters.role) {
    find.$and.push({ role: myFilters.role });
  }
  if (myFilters.jobs) {
    find.$and.push({ job: { $in: myFilters.jobs } });
  }
```

**Finally** , this is the db.collection call :

```
 db.collection("users")
      .find(find)
       .toArray(function(err, docs) {
           res.send(docs);
      });
```

SO , when a user doesn't pick a filter, the clean function is removing emptys selections ... Maybe there are better solutions ?

Comment: You must add these informations to the question, your answer has nothing to do with what you asked for, `$and` doesn't have the same effect as `$or`, I've updated my answer with a simpler version of what you want to do using `$where`